# How to replace letter keys, say v using autohotkey?

Tags: windows-7, autohotkey

One of the letters on my keyboard, v is not working and since I am  on windows 7, tried using autohotkey to replace this letter with another key combination like win+c or alt+c. But that is somehow not working and interferes with other key bindings.

The other answers I came across for this problem are for Ubuntu.

Doing c::v would not be ideal ofcourse.

I would prefer one key pressed twice to map to v.

```
cc::v
```

Is this possible or what are the alternatives ?

Comment: Buy a new keyboard?

Comment: Ofcourse :) but I am sure brilliant programmers have a solution for this little problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally agree with David, buy a new keyboard. If it is a laptop, you could try to repair it. Most likely there is a breadcrumb between the PCB and the rubber contact dome.

If you want to use AHK, and want to use a double tap c to generate a v, you could use this.

```
:?C*:cc::v
:?C*:CC::V
```

This would make writing words like Access difficult. You would have to write Ac<kbd>Space</kbd>c<kbd>Left</kbd><kbd>BackSpace</kbd><kbd>Right</kbd>ess.

Alternatively:

```
:?C*:cc::v
:?C*:CC::V
:?C*:c c::cc
:?C*:C C::CC
```

Allows you to write cc to get v and c<kbd>Space</kbd>c to get cc.

Background:

```
? means change inside a word
C means be case sensitive
* means do not require a trigger like space or return
```

Alternatively, and in my opinion better, you could use Win + c

```
#c::v
#+c::V
```

Or use a double x instead of double c

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am already using Win C for the paste function since that is where the v key gets used more. Laptop keyboard is preferrable over external ones and changing it for one key seems overkill and thats why searched for an AHK solution. And I got to learn new script in AHK. Thanks a lot.